# custom jquery error placement in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using jQueryplugin form validation and it works great, but it displays
the error message to the right of each form element. I actually want
the error message for each form element to be in a specific div that I
customize.

For example:

here is my validate rules.js

```
$("#form").validate({

    errorElement: "span", 


    //set the rules for the fields
    rules: {

        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength:25

        },
        phone:{
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength:10,
            maxlength:11
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        pswd: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength:15
        },
        pswd1: { 
            required :true,
            equalTo: "#pswd"
        }


    },
    //set messages to appear inline
    messages: {

        name: {
            required: "Name is required.."
        },

        pswd: {
            required: "Please provide a password.",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
            maxlength: "Password can not be more than 15 characters"
        },
        pswd1:{
            required: "Please re-Enter password.",
            equalTo:"password not matching"
        },
        phone:{
            required: "Please Enter phone no..",
            number:"Not a valid phone number ",
            minlength: "Not a valid phone number",
            maxlength: "Phone No. cannot be more than 11 digit"
        },
        email: "Valid email is required.",

    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {               
        error.appendTo(element.parent());     
    }

});
```

If anyone can tell me how you would do that it would be greatly
appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be work

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo('#div_id');
  }
});
```